# Cannot see loaded modules in hosted account

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, hosting

I am wanting to move my website online and my website is not working on my shared hosting account, only to find out that module mod_rewrite was not loaded. I ran phpinfo ( http://imranbukhsh.com/f/fcrawl/tmp/phpinfo.php) and I cannot see the whole section on 'loaded modules' which I can see on my personal computer after I installed XAMPP: its a huge section on my pc ( in phpinfo ) and totally missing on my shared hosting server.

My hosting company is Valcato

Thanking you

Comment: you can see the loaded modules in the `$_ENV["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]`

Answer (score 0):

The module is not loaded, which is why you are not seeing it in your server signature.